# How to declare a 3D vector variable?

Tags: vector, vector-calculus

How can I do vector calculations without telling Mathematica the vector entries?

I have very many arbitrary linear combinations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which I want to perform some general calculations on (scalar and vector products) and want to use Mathematica to do this (*especially for simplifying stuff like very long equations with scalar prodcuts of vector products*).

So, I don't want to write for all my vectors stuff like `v1={a1,b1,c1} ... vN={aN,bN,cN}` and so on, but just want to say `v1 ... vN` are vectors.

How is this possible?

Comment: You can start [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html).

Comment: You can always generate stuff like `v1={a1,b1,c1}` by defining a function, if you don't want to specify this manually.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming that we have three-dimensional real vectors :

```
$Assumptions = (u | v | w) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];
```

we can use e.g. various tensor functions (new in `ver. 9`)
e.g. `TensorReduce` to reduce (simplify) a tensor expression, e.g.

```
TensorReduce[ v.v + w.w - (v + w).(v + w) ]
TensorReduce[u \[Cross] (v \[Cross] w) ]
```

> ```
> -2 v.w
> -w u.v + v u.w
> ```

We can perform more interesting reductions, let's show e.g. the Jacobi identity:

```
TensorReduce[ u \[Cross] (v \[Cross] w) + v \[Cross] (w \[Cross] u) + 
              w \[Cross] (u \[Cross] v) ]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

or write it in a traditional form:

```
Defer[   u \[Cross] (v \[Cross] w) + v \[Cross] (w \[Cross] u)
       + w \[Cross] (u \[Cross] v)] == 
TensorReduce[   u \[Cross] (v \[Cross] w) + v \[Cross] (w \[Cross] u)
              + w \[Cross] (u \[Cross] v) ] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Another common identity

```
TensorExpand[ (u \[Cross] v) \[Cross] (u \[Cross] w) ]
TensorExpand[ (u \[Cross] v).(u \[Cross] v) ]
```

> ```
> u u \[Cross] v . w
> -(u.v)^2 + u.u  v.v
> ```

Take a look at new differential operators:

```
Curl[ Curl[ f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] == Laplacian[ f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: `{1, 2, 3} \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]` evaluates to `True`, yet `v + {1, 2, 3}` evaluates to `{1+v,2+v,3+v}`. Any suggestions on how to properly suppress this Listable attribute of Plus where it isn't appropriate?

Answer (score 6):

@Szabolcs is right, use Symbolic Tensors. But in that link it may be a bit confusing to find what you want. There are good examples on 3D vector operations. Read:

- [**Vectors**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Vectors.html)
- [**TensorExpand**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TensorExpand.html)
- [**Derive and Verify Vector Identities**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/DeriveAndVerifyVectorIdentities.html)

For example, proving an identity:

```
a\[Cross](b\[Cross](c\[Cross]d)) == b a.(c\[Cross]d) - (a.b) c\[Cross]d // TensorExpand
```

> True

Or expanding something very long:

```
((a\[Cross]b).c)^4 // TensorExpand
```

> (a.c)^4 (b.b)^2 - 4 a.b (a.c)^3 b.b b.c + 4 (a.b)^2 (a.c)^2 (b.c)^2 + 
>        2 a.a (a.c)^2 b.b (b.c)^2 - 
>        4 a.a a.b a.c (b.c)^3 + (a.a)^2 (b.c)^4 + 
>        2 (a.b)^2 (a.c)^2 b.b c.c - 2 a.a (a.c)^2 (b.b)^2 c.c - 
>        4 (a.b)^3 a.c b.c c.c + 4 a.a a.b a.c b.b b.c c.c + 
>        2 a.a (a.b)^2 (b.c)^2 c.c - 
>        2 (a.a)^2 b.b (b.c)^2 c.c + (a.b)^4 (c.c)^2 - 
>        2 a.a (a.b)^2 b.b (c.c)^2 + (a.a)^2 (b.b)^2 (c.c)^2

Comment: How can I add Real prefactors to the vectors with TensorExpand?