# how to distinguish clockwise from counterclockwise rotation

Tags: differential-equations, rotation

I need to distiguish the true rotation of a vector (time dependent, solution of a system of two coupled differential equation) respect a fixed vector. As showed in the follow,neither `VectorAngle` nor `ArcCos` work, because they yeld only positive results (i.e. as a counterclockwise rotation). I'm sure (from physical reasoning that the correct result is the opposite).

```
sol1 = FullSimplify[
   DSolve[{y'[t] == -3 y[t] - z[t], z'[t] == -0.6 z[t] + y[t], 
   y[0] == 0, z[0] == 1}, {y[t], z[t]}, t]];

{{Gy[t_], Gz[t_]}} = {-z[t], y[t]} /. sol1;

sol2 = FullSimplify[
   DSolve[{vy'[t] == -3 vy[t] - vz[t], 
 vz'[t] == -0.6 vz[t] +  vy[t], vy[T] == Gy[T], 
 vz[T] == Gz[T]}, {vy[t], vz[t]}, t]];

{{VY[t_], VZ[t_]}} = Simplify[{vy[t], vz[t]} /. sol2];

ang[T_]= VectorAngle[{Gy[0], Gz[0]}, {VY[0], VZ[0]}];

Plot[ang[T], {T, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

You can see, if you compile the code, that the plot result is:
[image: plot-output, but it'is incorrect]

I can obtain the correct result if I put an overall minus sign in `VectorAngle`, but obviously this is an incorrect procedure. I show her the output just for say you what is the "correct" output (as I said previously, I motivate it by physical reasoning)[image: correct plot-output]

Comment: To "orient a space" you need an external product like op. Try `Cross[]`

Comment: `ArcTan[x,y]` may be also used.

Comment: @Kuba: I think there is no difference between `ArcTan`, `ArcCos` and `VectorAngle` (I'have just try with `ArcCos` and I've obtain the same result)...

Comment: @belisarius : Then I have to embed the vectors in a 3D space...do you agree? But how I do this? I tried with:`Cross[{Normalize[{Gy[0], Gz[0], 0}]}, {Normalize[{VY[0], VZ[0], 0}]}]`...to extract a `Sin`...but I obtain an error

Comment: See this answer [Using the epsilon tensor in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/using-the-epsilon-tensor-in-mathematica/44035#44035) demonstrating how the `Curl` operator can be used for your purpuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a difference of `ArcTan` as Kuba implies.  `ArcSin @Last@Cross[{Normalize[{Gy[0], Gz[0], 0}]}, {Normalize[{VY[0], VZ[0], 0}]}]` has a similar problem with range that `VectorAngle` has.

```
ang[T_] = ArcTan[VY[0], VZ[0]] - ArcTan[Gy[0], Gz[0]];

Plot[ang[T], {T, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It also works this way:

```
Clear[ang];
ang[T0_?NumericQ] :=
  ArcTan @@ First @ RotationMatrix[{{VY[0], VZ[0]}, {Gy[0], Gz[0]}} /. T -> T0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was writting that I had the same problem with `Cross`, as you say, when you posted correct solution!