# Multiply out product of sums

Tags: programming, summation

For a specific quantum mechanical problem I need to multiply out operators in order to calculate a trace by hand. For example I need a Hamiltonian squared with $H^2$. The Hamiltonian contains of a few single terms and flip-flop terms embedded in sums like $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^N S_0^+ S_m^- + S_0^- S_m^+$.

My first idea was simply to write down the sums and ask Mathematica to multiply them out by expanding them. Unfortunately, this yields a result I could have imagined myself with $\sum_m (...) \times \sum_n (...)$. What I need is a sum of those product terms for example of the form $\sum_{m=1,n=1}^N S_0^+ S_m^-S_0^+ S_n^- + \sum_{m=1,n=1}^N (...)$ as I want to evaluate each operator separately by hand.

Changing the sum parenthesis doesn't seem to have any effect. Expand refuses to work.

Is there a possibility to let Mathematica multiply out all those terms individually?

Remark: As specific operators *don't* commute, e.g. $[S^+,S^-]$ for the same index I need Mathematica to give out *each* term. Simplifying by changing operator positions could lead to false results, so something like $(a+b)*(a+b)=a^2+ab+ba+b^2$ is needed here.

**Edit:** Here is a minimum example of what *doesn't* work as expected:

```
Expand[(-h Subscript[S^z, 0] - 
Sum[Subscript[J, 
  m] (Subscript[S, 0]^z Subscript[S, m]^z + 
    1/2 SuperPlus[Subscript[S, 0]] SuperMinus[Subscript[S, m]] + 
    1/2 SuperMinus[Subscript[S, 0]] SuperPlus[Subscript[S, 
     m]]), {m, 1, NN}]) (-h Subscript[S^z, 0] - 
Sum[Subscript[J, 
  n] (Subscript[S, 0]^z Subscript[S, n]^z + 
    1/2 SuperPlus[Subscript[S, 0]] SuperMinus[Subscript[S, n]] + 
    1/2 SuperMinus[Subscript[S, 0]] SuperPlus[Subscript[S, 
     n]]), {n, 1, NN}])]
```

Comment: If you can provide a minimum (non-)working example it would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: is `NN` known, or does it need to remain as `NN`?

Comment: Related: [Pull out scalars from NonCommutativeMultiply in commutator of SU2 spin algebra](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63811/245), and [Traces of products of Pauli matrices](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46593/245)

Comment: @chuy It has to remain that way. The variable is not known beforehand.

Comment: Note that even if the operators commuted, products of "simple" sums without definite bounds aren't automatically expanded by `Expand` either.  (I think this is what @chuy was driving at.) For example, `Expand[Sum[Subscript[a, i], {i, 1, NN}] Sum[Subscript[b, 
   i], {i, 1, NN}]]` just returns the product of the two sums.  So there are two separate issues here:  expanding an indefinite sum, and making sure operator order is preserved in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read [this](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/v7algebra.pdf). I used the package some time ago and it works quite nicely.