# Convert, using the Pauli matrices, an $n \times m$ matrix of quaternions into a $2 n \times 2 m$ matrix with complex entries, and vice versa

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex, quaternions

I'd like to go between $n \times m$ matrices with quaternionic entries to (using, it would seem, the Pauli matrix conversion scheme) to $2 n \times 2 m$ matrices with complex entries, and vice versa. I'd appreciate some efficient coding to accomplish this pair of tasks.

Say we have an $n \times m$ matrix the $n m$ entries of which are quaternions. We want to generate a $2 n \times 2 m$ matrix through the rule

```
Quaternion[a_, b_, c_, d_] -> 
  (a IdentityMatrix[2] - b PauliMatrix[1] - c PauliMatrix[2] - d PauliMatrix[3])
```

So, it seems that we have to appropriately reshape the resultant array (using, presumably, `ArrayReshape`) to the desired $2 n \times 2 m$ form.

Then, what off-hand seems more challenging, we want to be able to perform the inverse operation (going from the $2 n \times 2 m$ form to the [quaternionic-entry] $n \times m$ form]). Such an inverse operation would assume that the matrix to be transformed back possesses the indicated special (Pauli matrix) structure.

As some background to this problem, what I am really interested in accomplishing is finding the appropriate way to generate random quaternionic $4 \times 4$ density matrices with respect to Hilbert-Schmidt measure. The manner of accomplishing this for random complex $4 \times 4$ density matrices and 
random real $4 \times 4$ density matrices is presented in

https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.5094.pdf

(see eq. (1) and bot. p. 9 there). It seems that I may have to convert the $4 \times 4$ quaternionic-entry matrices to $8 \times 8$ form and use the developed rule for complex-entry matrices.

Some background references to the general quaternionic/Pauli matrix topic are (the amazingly detailed)

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271419/why-is-there-this-relationship-between-quaternions-and-pauli-matrices

and

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quaternion.html

which has a very explicit (eqs. (2)-(5)) straightforward treatment pertaining to the issue raised.

As well as wikipedia,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Quaternions

Comment: Please post any code you have tried and point out where exactly you're having difficulties. Without that, it will be difficult to write an answer that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Jens! Well, I was hoping for some code that would avoid having to go entry-by-entry, but rather work in some more "global" (presumably, more efficient) blockwise manner, possibly using the Partition (ArrayReshape?) command. Actually, I'm most interested in $4 \times 4$ and $2 \times 2$ matrices with quaternionic entries.

Comment: I think this will suffer the fate of all-too many questions that may be interesting but don't contain enough information to attract the attention of other *Mathematica* users. Remember this is a *Mathematica* and not a physics site. The form of the end result is actually quite ambiguous, I think.

Comment: Please take your time to edit into this question an example of the 2x2 and 4x4 matrices and define *what* the Pauli matrix conversion scheme is. As a physicist and a user of MMA I'll be happy to learn something outside of my field and to try solving a problem with my favorite tool. Once these details are included, I'll be more than willing to vote to reopen. VTC for now.

Comment: My guess is you need `KroneckerProduct`, similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46593/245). But it's only a guess until the desired input and output forms are described in more detail.

Comment: Looks like for the inverse operation you could use the orthogonality relation of the Pauli matrices as in [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63829/245), which actually does something very similar to what you're asking, by constructing matrices in a product space and transforming them back to operator notation.

Comment: Matrix `m` with dimensions `{4, 4, 2, 2} -> {8, 8}` can be done with `ArrayFlatten[m]`, and `{8, 8} -> {4, 4, 2, 2}` can be done with `Partition[m, {2, 2}]`.

Comment: Thanks, Carl Woll. This seems very helpful. Of course, these are the appropriate/natural ways to do the conversions. What's outstanding now it seems, is to how to express the derived {4,4,2,2} form back into the {4,4} form with explicitly quaternionic entries, that is, reverse the Quaternion[a_, b_, c_, d_] -> 
  (a IdentityMatrix[2] - b PauliMatrix[1] - c PauliMatrix[2] - d PauliMatrix[3])
operation.

Comment: I've expanded on the physics aspects of this problem in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340866/how-does-one-generate-a-random-n-times-n-density-matrix-with-quaternionic-ent

Answer (score 4):

Here are some functions to convert back and forth between quaternions and Pauli matrices:

```
basis = {IdentityMatrix[2], -PauliMatrix[1], -PauliMatrix[2], -PauliMatrix[3]};
$ProjectionMatrices = Transpose[basis, {3,1,2}]/2;

toQuant[m_] := Quaternion @@ Simplify @ Tr[m . $ProjectionMatrices, Plus, 2]
fromQuant[Quaternion[a_, b_, c_, d_]] := {a, b, c, d} . basis
```

So, a function to convert a matrix of quaternions to and from a "Pauli form" could be:

```
toPauli[m_] := ArrayFlatten[m /. q_Quaternion :> fromQuant[q]]

fromPauli[m_] := Map[toQuant, Partition[m, {2, 2}], {-3}]
```

For example:

```
m = Apply[Quaternion,RandomInteger[10,{4,4,4}],{2}]
```

> {{Quaternion[2, 3, 9, 4], Quaternion[1, 10, 9, 5], Quaternion[10, 0, 4, 9], 
>     Quaternion[0, 0, 8, 7]}, {Quaternion[10, 5, 6, 7], Quaternion[0, 5, 5, 8], 
>     Quaternion[8, 8, 1, 0], Quaternion[3, 3, 5, 10]}, {Quaternion[0, 7, 1, 4], 
>     Quaternion[5, 1, 3, 3], Quaternion[0, 0, 9, 8], 
>     Quaternion[4, 8, 1, 5]}, {Quaternion[6, 0, 4, 4], Quaternion[9, 7, 8, 3], 
>     Quaternion[1, 4, 6, 0], Quaternion[5, 2, 6, 10]}}

```
p = toPauli[m];
p //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  -2 & -3+9 i & -4 & -10+9 i & 1 & 4 i & -7 & 8 i \\
>  -3-9 i & 6 & -10-9 i & 6 & -4 i & 19 & -8 i & 7 \\
>  3 & -5+6 i & -8 & -5+5 i & 8 & -8+i & -7 & -3+5 i \\
>  -5-6 i & 17 & -5-5 i & 8 & -8-i & 8 & -3-5 i & 13 \\
>  -4 & -7+i & 2 & -1+3 i & -8 & 9 i & -1 & -8+i \\
>  -7-i & 4 & -1-3 i & 8 & -9 i & 8 & -8-i & 9 \\
>  2 & 4 i & 6 & -7+8 i & 1 & -4+6 i & -5 & -2+6 i \\
>  -4 i & 10 & -7-8 i & 12 & -4-6 i & 1 & -2-6 i & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
m == fromPauli[p]
```

> True

Comment: Looks great!--will study.

Comment: OK!. Now, how about going from the original $n \times m$ quaternionic -entried matrix to a $4 n \times 4 m$ real-entried matrix, and possibly vice versa--see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010172/represent-a-complex-valued-matrix-into-real-valued-matrix . Doing so may have some  value in addressing the eigenvalue problem for quaternionic Hermitian matrices http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377042712003822/1-s2.0-S0377042712003822-main.pdf?_tid=1479e256-584d-11e7-b566-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1498247553_c2c9350f891963559e0f89728d8fa2f6 .