# Symbolic tensor product calculation

Tags: symbolic, packages, tensors

I am trying to calculate the a symbolic tensor product

$\langle \nabla f\otimes f,\nabla g\otimes g\rangle ^2+(\langle \nabla f\otimes g,\nabla f\otimes g\rangle +\langle \nabla g\otimes f,\nabla g\otimes f\rangle +\langle \nabla g\otimes f,\nabla g\otimes g\rangle ) \langle \nabla f\otimes f,\nabla g\otimes g\rangle +4 \langle \nabla f\otimes g,\nabla f\otimes g\rangle ^2-\langle \nabla f\otimes f,\nabla f\otimes g\rangle  \langle \nabla f\otimes g,\nabla g\otimes g\rangle +8 \langle f\otimes g,g\otimes g\rangle  \langle \nabla f\otimes \nabla g,\nabla f\otimes \nabla g\rangle +\langle \nabla f\otimes f,\nabla f\otimes f\rangle  \langle \nabla g\otimes g,\nabla g\otimes g\rangle$

```
〈∇f⊗f, ∇g⊗g 〉^2 +  4 〈∇f⊗g, ∇f⊗g〉^2 - 〈∇f⊗f, ∇f⊗g〉 〈∇f⊗g, ∇g⊗g〉 + 
  〈∇f⊗f, ∇g⊗g〉 (〈∇f⊗g, ∇f⊗g〉 + 〈∇g⊗f, ∇g⊗f〉 + 〈∇g⊗f, ∇g⊗g〉) + 
  〈∇f⊗f, ∇f⊗f〉 〈∇g⊗g, ∇g⊗g〉 + 8 〈∇f⊗∇g, ∇f⊗∇g〉 〈f⊗g, g⊗g〉
```

Is there any *Mathematica* package to do this?

Welcome to any help

Comment: Take a look at related questions and then ask. See e.g. [42966](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42964/contracting-with-levi-civita-totally-antisymmetric-tensor/42966#42966) and [44035](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/using-the-epsilon-tensor-in-mathematica/44035#44035).

Comment: When I need to do some tensor calculcation I use http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/~sbonano/RGTC/ it is designed for general relativity but can handle basic tensor calculation. This one http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Ricci/ is often useful to.