# Verifying the anti-symmetric tensor identity

Tags: equation-solving, functions, tensors

I would like to verify

`Subscript[\[CurlyEpsilon], i\[InvisibleComma]j\[InvisibleComma]k] Subscript[\[CurlyEpsilon], i m n]=Subscript[\[Delta], j m] Subscript[\[Delta], k n]-Subscript[\[Delta], j n] Subscript[\[Delta], k m]`

I have defined:

`Subscript[\[Delta], i_Integer, j_Integer] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]`

`Subscript[\[Epsilon], i__Integer] := Signature[{i}]`

What is a good way to demonstrate the above identity holds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a more reliable approach than playing with `Sum`, just using `TensorProduct` and `TensorContract`,  e.g. [Contracting with Levi-Civita (totally antisymmetric) tensor](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42964/contracting-with-levi-civita-totally-antisymmetric-tensor/42966#42966) see also e.g. [Using the epsilon tensor in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/using-the-epsilon-tensor-in-mathematica/44035#44035).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoiding complicated and confusing subscripts and variable names until we have something working ... define

```
d[i_, j_] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]
e[i__Integer] := Signature[{i}]
```

The equivalence to prove is

```
equiv = Sum[e[i, j, k] e[i, m, n], {i, 1, 3}] == d[j, m] d[k, n] - d[j, n] d[k, m];
```

Check it for all possible values of the free variables

```
And @@ Flatten[Table[equiv, {n, 3}, {m, 3}, {l, 3}, {k, 3}, {j, 3}]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: I understand. But, my assignment question tend to come loaded with 'fancy' notation; 're-formatting' it may be tedious unless there are some formatting features by Mathematica that I am unaware of. For that I apologise. I have been called out before for this issue.