# Symmetry of Command Dot

Tags: geometry, dot

I would like to work with the command Dot assuming symmetry. Specifically with the order

`D[v[t].v[t], t]` I get the following output

`v[t].v'[t] + v'[t].v[t]`.

But I would like to get this one

`2 v[t].v'[t]`

Thanks in advice.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this would be `SetAttributes[Dot, Orderless]`. You can remove the `Orderless`  attribute afterwards with `ClearAttributes[Dot, Orderless]`. See also Carl Woll's answer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155396/72682 if you don't want to change attributes: `$Assumptions = (v[t] | v'[t]) \[Element] Vectors[2];
TensorReduce[D[v[t].v[t], t]]`