# How to add a vector variable to a vector value?

Tags: vector, assumptions, vector-calculus

If we have a three dimensional vector variable:

```
$Assumptions = a ∈ Vectors[3];
```

and a three dimensional vector value for example:

```
b = {1, 2, 3};
```

Then `a + b` evaluates to `{1 + a, 2 + a, 3 + a}`. We would expect the sum to generate `a + {1, 2, 3}`, because the elements of vector $\mathbf{a}$ are, as yet, unspecified. It looks *Mathematica* recognizes `a` as a scalars, which is not intended.

How can we get *Mathematica* to generate `a + {1, 2, 3}` as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is a consequence of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) attribute of [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus). This means that mixing explicit and symbolic vectors in arithmetic will not work correctly, and should be avoided.

Phrased another way: Since [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable), `a + {1, 2, 3}` will always evaluate to `{1+a, 2+a, 3+a}`. The only exceptions are when `a` evaluates to a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List) object, in which case it will thread, or issue a message if dimensions are incompatible. In other words, your desired endpoint will always evaluate further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why the replication is applied to `a`? It is assumed as a list, and the manual tells replication is applied only for that are not list.

Comment: Specific assumptions apply to specific transformations. `Plus` doesn't apply any assumptions at all, it simply sees `a` as a symbol, and transforms the expression accordingly. It's only a list if it has the head `List`.

Comment: @JohnDoty I see. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you so much for editing your answer. I completely understood how *Mathematica* recognizes and deals with `a`. Assuming object as a vectors is not equal to making list object! I hope *Mathematica* supports vector calculus which contains both explicit and symbolic vectors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to have things behave as you wish. Define your vector using Array (instead of trying to use an assumption:

```
aVec = Array[a, 3];
aVec + {1, 2, 3}
{1 + a[1], 2 + a[2], 3 + a[3]}
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I archive the intended result by not defining the vector elements? As another [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/how-to-declare-a-3d-vector-variable) says, I don't want to define new variables...